# How to create modified dataframe based on list values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-preprocessing

Consider a dataframe `df` of the following structure:-

```
Name    Slide          Height      Weight       Status       General
A           X             3            0.1             0.5       0.2
B           Y            10            0.2             0.7       0.8
    ...
```

I would like to create duplicates for each row in this dataframe (specific to the `Name` and `Slide`) for the following combinations of `Height` and `Weight` shown by this list:-

```
 list_combinations =  [[3,0.1],[10,0.2],[5,1.3]]
```

The desired output:-

```
Name    Slide          Height      Weight       Status       General
A           X             3            0.1             0.5       0.2 #original 
A           X             10           0.2             0.5       0.2 # modified duplicate
A           X             5            1.3             0.5       0.2 # modified duplicate
B           Y            10            0.2             0.7       0.8 #original 
B           Y             3            0.1             0.7       0.8 # modified duplicate
B           Y             5            1.3             0.7       0.8 # modified duplicate
  etc.  ...
```

Any suggestions and help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We can do `merge` with `cross`

```
out = pd.DataFrame(list_combinations,columns = ['Height','Weight']).\
          merge(df,how='cross',suffixes = ('','_')).\         
               reindex(columns=df.columns).sort_values('Name')
  Name Slide  Height  Weight  Status  General
0    A     X       3     0.1     0.5      0.2
2    A     X      10     0.2     0.5      0.2
4    A     X       5     1.3     0.5      0.2
1    B     Y       3     0.1     0.7      0.8
3    B     Y      10     0.2     0.7      0.8
5    B     Y       5     1.3     0.7      0.8
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @BENY. I am getting an error: 
KeyError: 'cross' on using this code.

Comment: @JChat please update your pandas :-)

Comment: okay thanks, I will update pandas! Also, there are multiple combinations of Name and Slide possible in my dataframe - such as A X as shown or things like A Z etc. Would this same code work for that too please (I just want to ensure that duplications are made corresponding to Name and Slide) and Height and Weight should change as per the list values i.e. for a given Name and Slide, the Height and Weight can vary as per the list_combinations but Status and General should remain same (I know it is confusing but thought to clarify). Thanks

Comment: I checked that I have Pandas 1.3.4.